# Does an Albanian citizen with a US green card need a visa to enter the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, us-residents, albanian-citizens

I need to travel to London from USA, and I am a green card holder. My nationality is Albanian. Do I need a visa to enter the UK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traveling without passport - just a Green Card - between US and UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56487/traveling-without-passport-just-a-green-card-between-us-and-uk)

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk nowhere does this question indicate a desire to travel without a passport.

Comment: maybe related? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35418/how-can-i-get-help-understanding-uk-visa-requirements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does an Indian national with a USA green card need a visa to visit the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116963/does-an-indian-national-with-a-usa-green-card-need-a-visa-to-visit-the-uk) and [Does a US Green Card holder with Iranian Passport need to obtain UK Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66476/does-a-us-green-card-holder-with-iranian-passport-need-to-obtain-uk-visa)

Comment: You only said "enter the UK", not "visit" or "move to". What is the purpose of your trip and for how long? Visit? Work?

Answer (score 15):

You can check if you need a UK visa at [this gov.uk web site](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).
I ran through it with your citizenship, and guessed that the purpose of your visit would be tourism, and the result is that you do need a visa.
Unlike some other countries, having a US green card does not give you visa-free (or visa on arrival) entry to the UK.
As noted by @MartinBonner in a comment, having a green card could improve the likelihood of your visa application being approved.

Comment: But note that the Home Office is much less likely to suspect a green-card holder of planning to overstay their visa, than an Albanian resident.